# Sweep Views left-right

Tags: iphone, navigation

We've got an application planned that is a very basic 7 page presetation. Our client wants to be able to sweep the views from right to left as a form of navigation, similar to the page control on the home screen.

I understand the presentModalViewController and pushViewController, but how do I detect a directional finger sweep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UIScrollView horizontal paging. [An Apple's sample code here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Just to add to this - take a look at the WWDC 104 video in iTunes U too, very good.

Comment: I can't find the video you have recommended danny, I've done a search but all I can find is podcasts, nothing on iTunes U

Comment: to find the videos, go to developer.apple.com, login. there u find them and u will be redirected to iTunes U.

Answer (score 0):

See [`UIScrollView`, and its `pagingEnabled` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled). UIKit does almost all of the work for you.